# Private variable in AppComponent constructor -> NO HTML/View?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, member-variables

Problem:

When adding (Visual Code autocompleted/-added) a variable (`private _dataService: DataService`) in AppComponent `constructor(…) { }` (because I used it down below) somehow the whole *UI output* **vanishes**.
When taken out of it (or moved above), all is **fine**.

**Why?**

Project is generated with Angular-CLI (no HTML customisations at this point). 
View output with `ng serve`.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './services/DataService'
import { isType } from '@angular/core/src/type';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(
    private _dataService: DataService
    // private translate: TranslateService
  ) { }

………
```

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 9.6.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.9

---

**EDIT**
Just realised I forgot the DataService to the Component (like I also see you already commented) :P!

-->

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService,Http]
})
```

But the Problem persists…

**Console output**:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: NullInjectorError: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
```

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: Any error in console? Do you have that `DataService` in `providers` array in your `AppModule`?

Comment: You need to add `DataService` in your `AppModule` providers. Check console logs, you'll be getting error details there.

Comment: @MartinAdámek & Faidal yup, added it, still breaking (see console output, now)

Comment: As the error states, you are missing another service in providers array: `No provider for ConnectionBackend`

Comment: @MartinAdámek `ConnectionBackend` is an Abstract class (from which real backends are derived)! So no chance there.

Comment: Ahh sorry, the problem is in `Http` I guess (that is not your service, right?). First of all, you should use `HttpClient` instead, as `Http` is now deprecated. Then you should not provide that, instead import `HttpClientModule` in your `AppModule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `HttpModule` is deprecated, use `HttpClientModule` instead (see https://angular.io/guide/http).

Then, you do not need to provide `HttpClient`, instead you need to `import` `HttpClientModule` in your `AppModule` to be able to use (inject) `HttpClient`.

So in your module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in your service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public doSomething() {
    return this.http.get('...');
  }
}
```